# Visual Studio Code and GIT

Tags: visual-studio

I started using GIT and now all of my personal files and folders are in the source section of Visual Studio Code. Everything is green with a “U”, even the practice programs that I have previously written.  I don’t want my personal files on VS Code.  Please advise.

Comment: You probably created your repository on some root folder level, encompassing all your other folders. Please tell us what the path to the root of your repository is so that we can advise you further.

Comment: You've tagged your question with Visual Studio not Visual Studio Code

Comment: Hello Lasse, Thank you for your quick response. I will be at my computer later today and submit the info that you requested. Sincerely, James Ferrari